# BeautifulSoup select method with CSS selector copied from inspecting element of a page returns nothing

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```py
link = 'http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028154.do'
req = requests.get(link)
bs = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
```

I want to obtain the book description within this page, I used inspect element and copied the CSS selector of the paragraph in question:

```py
bs.select('div.description:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(2)')
```

Unfortunately, the code returns an empty list and I have tried multiple variations of the code such as:

```py
bs.select('div.description:nth-of-type(2) > span:nth-of-type(2)')
```

```py
bs.select('div.description')
```

```py
bs.select('div#description t-description')
```

and all of them return an empty list, what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have the correct tags with the class you are looking for. The description is under a `<span>` tag, that you can get by finding the specific `<h2>` tag.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028154.do'
req = requests.get(link)
bs = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')

desc = bs.find('h2', {'class':'t-description-heading'}).find_next('span').text
```

or with `.select`

```
desc = bs.select('h2.t-description-heading')[0].find_next('span').text
```

**Output:**

```
'Get a comprehensive, in-depth introduction to the core Python language with this hands-on book. Based on author Mark Lutz’s popular training course, this updated fifth edition will help you quickly write efficient, high-quality code with Python. It’s an ideal way to begin, whether you’re new to programming or a professional developer versed in other languages.Complete with quizzes, exercises, and helpful illustrations,  this easy-to-follow, self-paced tutorial gets you started with both Python 2.7 and 3.3— the latest releases in the 3.X  and 2.X lines—plus all other releases in common use today. You’ll also learn some advanced language features that recently have become more common in Python code.Explore Python’s major built-in object types such as numbers, lists, and dictionariesCreate and process objects with Python statements, and learn Python’s general syntax modelUse functions to avoid code redundancy and package code for reuseOrganize statements, functions, and other tools into larger components with modulesDive into classes: Python’s object-oriented programming tool for structuring codeWrite large programs with Python’s exception-handling model and development toolsLearn advanced Python tools, including decorators, descriptors, metaclasses, and Unicode processing'
```

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve this information via the .select method as well?